# jQuery autocomplete combobox with searchable label AND description of option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'd like to use [multirow autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) from jQuery UI but with searchable both label and description of options. Or label and value, but value would had to be visible for user.

Is there any way to do it?

Update:
Also button (down arrow) to display (perhaps scrollable) list of all the options would be nice.

Comment: I tried some examples and browsed theirs code. I also read autocomplete's documentation but I couldn't find a way to do what I want.

Comment: Is the filtering being completed on the server side or on the client side? I think that you should post some code to see if we can assist.

Comment: I imagine filtering to be client-sided since there would be only approx. 100 option elements loaded initially from DB. As I wrote before, I don't have any particular code to hold on to myself yet. I only studied different examples posted all over the net and on jQueryUI site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely doable. Adapting the answer you linked to, here's how you would search by the `desc` property of each item, as well as the `label` property. This examples also incorporates a jQueryUI button (`#showall`) that shows all items.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    var projects = [ /* ... */ ];

    $("#showall").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
        .on("click", function () {
            $("#project").autocomplete("search", "");
        });


    $("#project").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            /* Search by description or label: */
            response($.grep(projects, function(value) {
                return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value) || 
                    matcher.test(value.desc);
            }));
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-id").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
            $("#project-icon").attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon);

            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Your preferred programming language:</label>
    <span class="ui-combobox">
        <input id="project" type="text" class="ui-combobox-input ui-state-default ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" /><a id="showall" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items"></a>
    </span>
</div>​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/4/

Try searching for "CSS" or "interface"

Comment: Awesome! I don't know how I could not see that! Thank you!